# C# Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I want to use C# Facebook SDK for my WPF project, but all I get from download link is 404 error. I can't even go to link for feedback withouth having 404 error. This is going for few days and I don't know where else to find C# Facebook SDK. Also I want to find a very good documentation how to use that SDK. Sorry if some similar or same question has been asked but please answer here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The project was moved from [`codeplex`](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com) to [`Github`](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk), as you can see downloading [`this README`](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/downloads/get/340200).

Comment: ok I have download it via nuget in cmd. what about documentation? Or to be more specific how to post a picture with description on Facebook page like http://www.facebook.com/TennisHelper

Comment: We have are two questions here. The first: **Old** Facebook `SDK C# doc` http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation?version=94 the **new** Facebook `C# SDK doc`: http://csharpsdk.org/ and the `Facebook` **API** `doc`: http://developers.facebook.com/. The second: must be asked into separated question.